# Adding Knowlege Base article to solution/resolution field in incident

Tags: servicenow

I'm looking at promoting the Service Now KB with our organisation and have noticed that by clicking the "book" icon beside short description, you can attach an KB article to the incident, but this goes into the additional comments.

Is it possible that the book icon can appear beside the solution field when resolving the incident so it will then appear in the resolution field and go via email to the user?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are still looking for an answer , look for the attribute

> knowledge_search

in service now wiki , will be able to find what you are looking for

And also look for contextual search in service now

As far as email goes , thats something that you have to customize using mail script I believe

Hope it helps if you are still interested !!!